# Docker build Unreal image ERROR (CorruptPackFileException) (step 28)

Tags: docker

I want to build the docker image for the Unreal Carla project.

For that, I get struggle with following command:

```
ue4-docker build 4.22.2 --no-engine --no-minimal
```

I get the follwing error:

```
 Step 28/34 : RUN ./Setup.sh && echo '' && echo 'RUN directive complete. 
 ---> Running in 9734d2ffdb00
.... 

Registering git hooks... (this will override existing ones!)
Fixing inconsistent case in filenames.
Setting up Mono
Checking dependencies...

Updating dependencies:  18% (12936/41030), 1702.0/9123.9 MiB | 5.04 MiB/s... 
Failed to download 'http://cdn.unrealengine.com/dependencies/3215544-fbbce13ceb6f4aaea59e20af2d659d08/36799aacce147eba397f6eacc7a0f6c9dac946d8': 

Can't read from pack stream (CorruptPackFileException)
Result: 1

The command '/bin/sh -c ./Setup.sh && echo '' && echo 'RUN directive complete. Docker will now commit the filesystem layer to disk.' && echo 'Note that for large filesystem layers this can take quite some time.' && echo 'Performing filesystem layer commit...' && echo ''' returned a non-zero code: 1

[ue4-docker build] Error: failed to build image "adamrehn/ue4-source:4.22.2-opengl".
```

I guess that the main problem is  about `CorruptPackFileException`. Unfortunately I don't how to deal with that.

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance.